# email input validation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I need to validate the value of an e-mail input. I have this code but it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="mail" class="mail" /> 
<button class="validate">VALIDATE</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var setMail = $(".mail").val();
    var mailVal = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/; 

    $(".validate").click(function(){
        if (mailVal == setMail) {
            alert("GOOD!");
            }
            else{ 
            alert("WRONG!");
            }
   });
});
```

[JSFiddle: DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hr8xbh27/2/)

Comment: Edit the following : if (mailVal.test(setMail)) {   to if (mailVal.test($(".mail").val())) {  because as of now setMail is only get at page load which will be empty so you are not validating anything.

Comment: You should restructure your code in a more efficient way and bind the input field to .focusout() this way you can do a validation without requiring a click button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery validation library. It does many validation for you with an easy implementation way. Such like-

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

documentation source link-
[jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method)

Answer (score 1):

mailVal isn't going to equal setMail. You want to check for a match: `mailVal.test($(".mail").val())` instead of the `==` test.

Comment: I would also suggest that the input type be changed to "email" and the regex changed to be the following to follow W3C standards for email validation: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/